# Ableton Push - Python script LED feedback.

Tags: python, led, ableton-live

I've recently started learning about Python scripting in order modify Ableton Pushs behaviour.

In the process of learning I've come across a few scripts (paid) that do some interesting things. One in particular seems to provide the ability to switch the push into a sort of 'mix mode' which allows the Push to receive information about the level (VU Meter) of the 8 currently selected tracks & master (the master VU is displayed horizontally).

I've been exploring the _framework and i've seen a few things that would be responsible for button colors, but I can't seem to identify what would be responsible for real-time visual feedback.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation for achieving this on the APC40:

[VU Metering with Remote Scripts](http://alijamieson.co.uk/2015/04/levels-apc40-remix-vu-metering-in-hardware-with-remote-scripts/)

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/matthewcieplak/APC_64_40_9/blob/master/VUMeters.py)

This could be easily added to the Push script... :)

[Ableton Live User Remote Scripts for Live 9](https://github.com/gluon/AbletonLive9_RemoteScripts)

PS: There might be some nice updates for the scripts in the newly released Live 9.2, but I don't know if they are available anywhere, yet.